# How Can CKEditor handle custom semantic mark-up?

Tags: ckeditor, semantic-markup

I need a WYSIWYG editor that can be customised for arbitrary semantic mark-up -- currently represented in an XML grammar. I know CKEditor is customisable but my semantics have no correspondence in HTML.

For instance:

**<Place Id='place-id'>place reference</Place>**

I want to be able to attach semantics similar to this to arbitrary bits of text, and have them displayed using a configurable set of styles -- one for each type of semantic. For instance, the place-reference in this example might be displayed in a specific font, in green, and in italics (suggested here only for illustration).

I have looked briefly at the markdown add-on but its capabilities are still matched by those of HTML.

I was hoping to find a very simple example that demonstrated the editor's applicability to purely custom semantics, and without assuming they have a correspondence in HTML/XHTML.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Each piece of custom mark-up will have both a semantic aspect (the place reference and the ID in my example above) and a presentational aspect (how do I want to see that marked-up reference depicted). If the custom mark-up is replaced with a <span> or <div> of a specific class then it can represent both aspects, and should be acceptable to HTML editors such as CKEditor -- currently unproven.

For instance, consider another example of custom XML mark-up that has several attribute values:

```
<Anom Mode='Intralinear' Posn='T' Ref='^'> some text </Anom>
```

This could be converted as follows to make it acceptable to the editor (where "xx" is some unique proprietary name to avoid name clashes):

```
<span class="xx-anom" data-xx-mode="Intralinear" data-xx-posn="T" data-xx-ref="^"> some text </span>
```

As well as capturing the attribute values, I believe this should allow the editor to display different pieces of marked-up text according to different styles, using some CSS that has selectors such as span.xx-anom.

CKeditor already has third-party plug-ins for markdown and BBCode, and these demonstrate how to edit their syntax using HTML as a temporary representation. It should be possible to do the same for custom XML mark-up too.

Comment: That would indeed be the recommended solution. Feeding CKEditor with HTML it can understand (without having all features rewritten to accommodate custom markup) by transforming the input and output is, in general, solution for many troubles, because it separates concerns. CKEditor can focus on editing semantical HTML, while the external logic is kept outside, in the transformator code. Later on you may decide that you need to customise how the transformed content can be edited (e.g. what can be nested where). That's where things become more complicated, because you cannot avoid (...)

Comment: (...) writing your own plugins. And there are technical limitations (both, browsers' and CKEditor's) which such plugins cannot reasonably overcome.  So depending on the level of content control which one wants to implement, it may turn out that CKEditor 4 may not handle such a task. Fortunately, [CKEditor 5](https://medium.com/content-uneditable/ckeditor-5-the-future-of-rich-text-editing-2b9300f9df2c#.k19bka2r3) will greatly extend this possibilities by introduction of a new data model.

Comment: Thanks for this endorsement. I do not quite understand what limitations I am likely to encounter. The editor only needs to understand HTML, and simply keep a copy of any semantic information. Will plug-ins have the same interface when the new data model is released?

Comment: Do you mean the API for building plugins or the UI of the existing plugins? In fact, both will change. CKEditor 5 is a new project, despite the name.

Comment: I was referring to your previous comment: ..."it may turn out that CKEditor 4 may not handle such a task" because I wasn't certain what you meant. My nesting rules would be relatively simple. However, I would also need to customise the toolbar to include corresponding buttons for adding my mark-up (in its HTML form). It would be great to have a simple example that does all this for a couple of instances of custom mark-up (maybe even the two cited here) since JS is one of the few languages I've never really used until now.